# Only single record getting when i fetch data from another page

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a php page for fetch all data from mysql and i have another page to show data on webpage....
i have php page its like page_1.php

```
<?php  include_once'db_localconnection.php';

    $query="SELECT * FROM `table 5` where base='Home Plans'";
    $get_allplans=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($get_allplans))
    {

        $plans_code=$fetch['plan_code'];
        $speed=$fetch['speed'];
        $data=$fetch['data'];
        $duration=$fetch['duration'];
        $gb_pm=$fetch['gb_pm'];
        $up_speed=$fetch['up_speed'];
        $price=$fetch['price'];
        $base=$fetch['base'];
    }    
?>
```

and i have another page for show data i have also include all needed pages

```
    <td><?php echo $plans_code; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $speed; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $duration; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $gb_pm; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $up_speed; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
    <td><a href="#">get reacharge</a></td>
```

so i am getting only first record please help..

Answer (score 0):

You storing the values from db to variables i.e $plans_code, etc. in WHILE statement you just overwriting the values each time you loop. Instead, store them into array and send to your second page and display them.

example:

```
$completeData = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_allplans))
{
   array_push($completeData, $row);
}
```

now fetch the array $completeData to your second page and then display it,
like:

```
<?php  foreach($completeData as $row) { ?>
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['plans_code']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['speed']; ?></td>
   .
   .
   .
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```